# Integrating Ninject in an asmx Web Service

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, ninject

What is the best way of integrating Ninject in a Soap Web Service?

I tried with NuGet and Ninject.Wcf package. But I get an error when I try to consume an asmx service without a parameterless constructor.

A service looks like:

```
public class Authentication : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private readonly IDosReactingAuthentication dosReactingAuthentication;

    public Authentication(IDosReactingAuthentication dosReactingAuthentication)
    {
        this.dosReactingAuthentication = dosReactingAuthentication;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public bool Auth(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        return dosReactingAuthentication.Auth(domain, username, password);
    }
}
```

When I consume the `Auth()` service I always get `System.MissingMethodException: no parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

I also tried with property injection but the dependency is always equal to null.

Comment: What is the error? and what have you tried (show some code)

Comment: @christiandev I installed NuGet/Ninject.Wcf package. I provided the bindings which are correctly configured at application startup. When I run the service and try to consume it, I get System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ---> System.MissingMethodException: no parameterless constructor defined for this object.